# Why do transitions no longer work in LibreOffice Impress since upgrading to 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, graphics, libreoffice, opengl

I'm having this issue on two systems - one with Nvidia graphics (dedicated), and the other with Intel graphics.

On both systems, OpenGL is disabled, and enabling it by ignoring blacklisting (which forces the program to use OpenGL for all rendering), doesn't fix the problem. Strangely, it also causes the hardware acceleration toggle to be disabled.

Both systems are running LibreOffice 6.1.x directly from the standard repositories. All I did was upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04.

Colour me confused.

What could be the issue here?

### Update:

I tried running LibreOffice without GTK (by removing GTK support), as this has been a solution in the past, but it didn't change the situation. Still getting no transitions whatsoever.

### Further Update:

I tried LibreOffice in the MATE desktop environment, with both Compton and Marco as compositors, and this made no difference. Clearly, whether or not hardware acceleration is being used by the window manager/compositor is not the issue. It has been an issue in the past, but it's not the case here.